# Unable to start Azure Storage Emulator

Tags: azure-storage-emulator

I've run into problems trying to run the Azure Storage Emulator on a newly installed computer.

At first it was returning

> Cannot create database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb56' : The database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb56' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases..

However, when I ran `sqllocaldb i` I could see that there *was* a DB named 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb56'.

I eventually ran the command

```
AzureStorageEmulator init -server localhost -forcecreate
```

which returned

> Granting database access to user AzureAD\[username elided].
>   Database access for user AzureAD\[username elided] was granted.
>
> Initialization successful. The storage emulator is now ready for use.
>   The storage emulator was successfully initialized and is ready to use.

which looks promising.

However, when I right-click the emulator's icon in the system try and select "Start Storage Emulator" nothing happens. And if I then look in the log files I can see an error log (Error20-Jul-18-11-07.log) which contains...

> 7/20/2018 11:06:36 AM [Error] [ActivityId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] Input string was not in a correct format.

There's also an `Info20-Jul-18-11-07.log` file which contains

> 7/20/2018 11:06:36 AM [Info] [ActivityId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] Starting Service: Blob
>   7/20/2018 11:06:36 AM [Info] [ActivityId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] Stopping Service: Blob

Can anyone explain what's going wrong and how I can get the local storage emulator up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable logging, there seems to be a bug in the 5.5 release:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/728